# The space complexity is always the lower bound of the time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, analysis

My book states that for a code with T(n) time complexity and S(n) space complexity, the following statement holds: 
T(n) is omega(S(n)). 
My question is: Why does this statement hold?

Comment: Because it takes time to allocate space.

Comment: Please refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Because think like this. To create array of `n^2` element it will atleast take `n^2` time. So any time you cannot allocate for example `n` elements in constant time `O(1)`. And thus space complexity will always be lower bound of time complexity.

Comment: Keep in mind that space complexity doesn't include the space occupied by the input. (For example, binary search on an array has logarithmic time complexity but constant  space complexity.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between time complexity and space complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686121/differences-between-time-complexity-and-space-complexity)

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you're writing very low-level code (i.e. not Python) that is allowed to ask for memory without having it zeroed out first, then you can write algorithms which use "more space than time". There's a nice example in one of the early exercises in *Programming Pearls* by John Bentley, of using two uninitialised arrays to represent a set of integers; the number `i` is in the set if and only if `arr1[i] < size` and `arr2[arr1[i]] == i`. The idea is that you can write at random positions in `arr1` and use `arr2` to confirm whether a position in `arr1` has been written or not.

Answer (score 5):

We are speaking of ***sequential*** algorithms.

Then space complexity S(n) means that the algorithm somehow inspects each of S(n) different memory locations at least once. In order to visit this many memory locations a sequential algorithm needs Ω(S(n)) time.